# Function definition not allowed here

Tags: c

I have the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    void echoNumber()
    {
        int num;
        printf("Enter a number:");
        scanf("%d", &num);
        printf("You entered %d", num);
    }
    echoNumber();
    return 0;
}
```

but when I attempt to compile it it returns `error: function definition is not allowed here` , I am not sure what I am doing wrong?

Comment: The error message is actually correct ...

Comment: You can't define function inside another function.

Comment: I really am not a troll, I am following a course on C for the first time, just got to the part on functions and they did not mention this

Comment: @justin Why would an intro course mention that you *can't* do something? It's hard enough teaching how to do what you can do. There are an infinite number of things you can't do.

Comment: Note that (at least some versions of) GCC will allow that unless you tell it not to.  It's an extension to C — one I regard as not very helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Function definitions go outside of main() in `C`

```
#include <stdio.h>

void echoNumber() {
    int num;

    printf("Enter a number:");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    printf("You entered %d", num);
}

int main() {
    echoNumber();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I feel i've purchased a terrible tutorial, didn't mention that or how to compile and run a c program...thanks though I appreciate the fast response

Comment: @justin read through [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c?sort=votes&pageSize=50), it will help a lot. There's a post somewhere which has a list of really good resources, you'll probably find it when you're reading through these posts.

Answer (score 2):

C doesn't have nested functions. Move `echoNumber` outside of `main`, e.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void echoNumber()
{
    int num;
    printf("Enter a number:");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    printf("You entered %d", num);
}

int main()
{
    echoNumber();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing wrong is simply not realising that C is not Pascal :-) Pascal has the concept of functions within functions where the "visibility" of the former is limited to the latter. In other words, you can't see the inner function from anywhere else.

There is no facility in C to have functions within functions. The closest equivalent to what you have is:

```
#include <stdio.h>

static void echoNumber()
{
    int num;
    printf("Enter a number:");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    printf("You entered %d", num);
}

int main()
{
    echoNumber();
    return 0;
}
```

The `static` in front of `echoNumber` limits it's "visibility" to that of the rest of the file. That's not *quite* as restrictive as the Pascal model but, provided you organise your code nicely, will be equally efficient.

---

You'll note I've quoted the word visibility above. I'm using the the common English term (for "where you can see it from") rather than the preoper ISO standards ones, since I find that's more understandable to those who aren't intimately immersed in the standard.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
void echoNumber()
{
    int num = 0;
    puts("Enter a number:");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    printf("You entered %d", num);
}
int main()
{

  echoNumber();
   return 0;
}
```

The issue is, in C that is not how you declare a function. Unless you meant to not declare echoNumber and just meant that code to be local scope do this

```
int main()
{
    {
    int num = 0;
    puts("Enter a number:");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    printf("You entered %d", num);
    }
    return 0;
}
```