# How to debug this error in C: function definition is not allowed here?

Tags: c, cs50

I am new to programming and am taking edX's CS50 (Intro to Programming) class. There is this C code that I have been trying to compile, but always results in an error message that looks like this:
[image: error message]

This is the code lines that I have been trying to compile:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main (void)
{
   bool valid_triangle (float a, float b, float c);
   bool valid_triangle (float a, float b, float c)
  {
   // check positive values
     if ( a <= 0 || b <= 0 || c <= 0 )
    {
    return false;
     }
    //check two sides are longer
    if ( (a + b <= c) || (a+c <= b) || (b+c <= a))
    {
    return false;
    }

    //otherwise return true
     return true;
 }

}
```

Does anyone know what I did wrong and how to fix this error? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'd be more worried how to fix the syntax so it *compiles* before I worry about the bugs. The error message is self-explanatory. You can't define nested functions in C. `valid_triangle` should be defined *outside* of `main`.

Comment: I put `bool valid_triangle (float a, float b, float c);` above the `int(main)` as you said. It still doesn't work :(

Comment: You have to move the whole thing out of `main` not just the forward declaration. You cannot define a function from inside another function.

Comment: That means you’ve moved the *declaration* of valid_triangle outside of main. Move the definition also (line 6-21).

Comment: Oh now it works!! Thanks so much guys! But can someone explain to me as to why the int main(void) is needed here? I thought that it is needed at the very top of the code to "trigger" the codes below to work... but apparently that's not the case.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Function definition not allowed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51488853/function-definition-not-allowed-here) Please do at least a basic search for the error message here before posting; chances are very good that it's been asked about here before.

Comment: The `main()` function is where the execution starts.  So, in C, always need exactly one instance of a `main()` function.

Comment: regarding: `#include <math.h>`  it is a poor programming practice to include header files those contents are nor used

Comment: Ah okay, now I get it, thanks @user3629249 and everyone! Thanks for the advice too! :)

Answer (score 1):

the following proposed code:

1. performs the indicated functionality
2. cleanly compiles
3. displays one way to have sub functions in C

and now, the proposed code:

```
//#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>   // putc()
//#include <math.h>
#include <stdbool.h> // bool, true, false


bool valid_triangle (float a, float b, float c)
{
    // check positive values
    if ( a <= 0 || b <= 0 || c <= 0 )
    {
        return false;
    }

    //check two sides are longer
    if ( (a + b <= c) || (a+c <= b) || (b+c <= a))
    {
        return false;
    }

    //otherwise return true
    return true;
}


int main (void)
{
    float a = 1;
    float b = 2;
    float c = 3;

    if( valid_triangle (a, b, c) )
    {
       puts( "able to calculate triangle area" );
    }

    else
    {
       puts( "area of triangle cannot be calculated" );
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Compiler error messages are your best friend, so use them to your advantage. Here, your error message `triangle.c:9.6` tells you that your error is on line 9. Also, it spits out the string `error: function definition is not allowed here.`

In C, a procedural language, function definitions are not allowed inside of other functions.

To fix this, either define your function before your `main()` function, and then just call your `valid_triangle` function from your main function. Another way to organize your code would to put the `valid_triangle` function prototype before the `main` function, and then define the `valid_triangle` below the body of the `main` function.

Remember, the main() function is the point of entry for your program.